# Looking for cause of unexpected preemption in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, real-time, smp

I have a small linux kernel module that is a prototype for a device driver for hardware that doesn't exist yet.  The code needs to do a short bit of computation as fast as possible from beginning to end with a duration that is a few microseconds.  I am trying to measure whether this is possible with the intel rdtscp instruction using an `ndelay()` call to simulate the computation. I find that 99.9% of the time it runs as expected, but 0.1% of the time it has a very large delay that appears as if something else is preempting the code despite running inside a spinlock which should be disabling interrupts.  This is run using a stock Ubuntu 64 bit kernel (4.4.0-112) with no extra realtime or low latency patches.

Here is some example code that replicates this behavior.  This is written as a handler for a `/proc` filesystem entry for easy testing, but I have only shown the function that actually computes the delays:

```
#define ITERATIONS 50000
#define SKIPITER 10
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(timer_lock);
static int timing_test_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) 
{
  uint64_t i;
  uint64_t first, start, stop, delta, max=0, min=1000000;
  uint64_t avg_ticks;
  uint32_t a, d, c;
  unsigned long flags;
  int above30k=0;

  __asm__ volatile ("rdtscp" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "rcx");
  first = a | (((uint64_t)d)<<32);
  for (i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) {
    spin_lock_irqsave(&timer_lock, flags);
    __asm__ volatile ("rdtscp" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "rcx");
    start = a | (((uint64_t)d)<<32);
    ndelay(1000);
    __asm__ volatile ("rdtscp" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "rcx");
    stop = a | (((uint64_t)d)<<32);
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&timer_lock, flags);
    if (i < SKIPITER) continue;
    delta = stop-start;
    if (delta < min) min = delta;
    if (delta > max) max = delta;
    if (delta > 30000) above30k++;
  }
  seq_printf(m, "min: %llu max: %llu above30k: %d\n", min, max, above30k);
  avg_ticks = (stop - first) / ITERATIONS;
  seq_printf(m, "Average total ticks/iteration: %llu\n", avg_ticks);
  return 0;
}
```

Then if I run:

```
# cat /proc/timing_test
min: 4176 max: 58248 above30k: 56
Average total ticks/iteration: 4365
```

This is on a 3.4 GHz sandy bridge generation Core i7.  The ~4200 ticks of the TSC is about right for a little over 1 microsecond delay.  About 0.1% of the time I see delays about 10x longer than expected, and in some cases I have seen times as long as 120,000 ticks.

These delays appear too long to be a single cache miss, even to DRAM.  So I think it either has to be several cache misses, or another task preempting the CPU in the middle of my critical section.  I would like to understand the possible causes of this to see if they are something we can eliminate or if we have to move to a custom processor/FPGA solution.

Things I have tried:

- I considered if this could be caused by cache misses.  I don't think that could be the case since I ignore the first few iterations which should load the cache.  I have verified by examining disassembly that there are no memory operations between the two calls to rdtscp, so I think the only possible cache misses are for the instruction cache.
- Just in case, I moved the spin_lock calls around the outer loop.  Then it shouldn't be possible to have any cache misses after the first iteration.  However, this made the problem *worse*.
- I had heard that the SMM interrupt is unmaskable and mostly transparent and could cause unwanted preemption.  However, you can read the SMI interrupt count with `rdmsr` on `MSR_SMI_COUNT`.  I tried adding that before and after and there are no SMM interrupts happening while my code is executing.
- I understand there are also inter-processor interrupts in SMP systems that may interrupt, but I looked at /proc/interrupts before and after and don't see enough of them to explain this behavior.
- I don't know if `ndelay()` takes into account variable clock speed, but I think the CPU clock only varies by a factor of 2, so this should not cause a >10x change.
- I booted with nopti to disable page table isolation in case that is causing problems.

Comment: Are you a running 32- or 64-bit kernel? What compiler flags are you using? Can you also post the relevant assembler output from the function?

Comment: have you checked NMIs?

Comment: Its a 64 bit kernel.  I am using the default compiler flags from the kernel package makefile.  I don't see and accumulating NMI or SMI interrupts.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code as tasklet under a kernel with preemption patches?

Comment: [This Intel document](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf) discusses the effects of out-of-order execution on measurements based on the RDTSC instruction. It also covers some other aspects that you may need to take into account. Since you haven't posted an MCVE, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that I have just noticed is that it is unclear what `ndelay()` does. Maybe you should show it so as non-trivial problems may be lurking inside it.

For example, I've observed once that my piece of a kernel driver code was still preempted when it had a memory leak inside it, so as soon as it hit some watermark limit, it was put aside even if it disabled interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

120,000 ticks that you observed in extreme cases sounds a lot like an SMM handler. Lesser values might have been caused by an assortment of microarchitectural events (by the way, have you checked all the performance counters available to you?), but this is something that must be caused by a subroutine written by someone who was not writing  his/her code to achieve minimal latency.

However you stated that you've checked that no SMIs are observed. This leads me to think that either something is wrong with kernel facilities to count/report them, or with your method to look after them. Hunting after SMI without a hardware debugger may be a frustrating endeavor.

- Was SMI_COUNT not changing during your experiment course, or was it exactly zero all the time? The latter might indicate that it does not count anything, unless you system is completely free from SMI, which I doubt of in case of regular Sandy Bridge.
- It may be that SMIs are delivered to another core in your system, and an SMM handler is synchronizing other cores through some sort of mechanism that does not show up on SMI_COUNT. Have you checked other cores?
- In general I would recommend starting downsizing your system under test to exclude as much of stuff as possible. Have you tried booting it with a single core and no hyperthreading enabled in BIOS? Have you tried to run the same code on a system that is known to not have SMIs? The same goes with disabling Turbo Boost and Frequency scaling in BIOS. As much as possible of timing-related must go.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in my system:

```
timingtest % uname -a
Linux xxxxxx 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Replicating your example (with ndelay(1000);) I get:

```
timingtest % sudo cat /proc/timing_test
min: 3783 max: 66883 above30k: 20
Average total ticks/iteration: 4005

timingtest % sudo cat /proc/timing_test
min: 3783 max: 64282 above30k: 19
Average total ticks/iteration: 4010
```

Replicating your example (with udelay(1);) I get:

```
timingtest % sudo cat /proc/timing_test
min: 3308 max: 43301 above30k: 2
Average total ticks/iteration: 3611

timingtest % sudo cat /proc/timing_test
min: 3303 max: 44244 above30k: 2
Average total ticks/iteration: 3600
```

ndelay(),udelay(),mdelay() are for use in atomic context as stated here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt
They all rely on __const_udelay() funtion that is a vmlinux exported symbol (using: LFENCE/RDTSC instructions).

Anyway, I replaced the delay with:

```
for (delta=0,c=0; delta<500; delta++) {c++; c|=(c<<24); c&=~(c<<16);}
```

for a trivial busy loop, with the same results.

I also tryed with _cli()/_sti(), local_bh_disable()/local_bh_enable() and preempt_disable()/preempt_enable() without success.

Examinig SMM interrupts (before and after delay) with:

```
__asm__ volatile ("rdmsr" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : "c"(0x34) : );
smi_after = (a | (((uint64_t)d)<<32));
```

I always obtain the same number (no SMI or register not updated).

Executing the cat command with trace-cmd to explore what's happening, I get results suprissingly not so scattered in time. (!?)

```
timingtest % sudo trace-cmd record -o trace.dat -p function_graph cat /proc/timing_test 
  plugin 'function_graph'
min: 3559 max: 4161 above30k: 0
Average total ticks/iteration: 5863
...
```

In my system, the problem can be solved making use of Power management Quality of Service, see (https://access.redhat.com/articles/65410). Hope this helps